# Stacked Bar Graph of Count of Variables within date bins

Tags: r

Using R, I am trying to make a simple stacked bar graph of the counts of different settlement types by date. I have 3 ways of accounting for date. Below is an example of my database

`ID Settlement  Start  End  Mid
01  Urban      200    400  300
02  Rural      450    850  650
03  Military   1300   1400 1350
04  Castle     2      1000 501`

so far I have

> count(ratData, vars = "Settlement")

which returns

`Settlement freq
1                        78
2               Castle   25
3                 Cave    3
4        Fortification    5
5            Hill Fort    2
6  Industrial (quarry)    1
7                Manor    2
8             Military    4
9        Military camp    1
10       Military Camp    3
11       Military site    1
12              Mining    1
13            Monastic   15
14     Monastic/Rural?    1
15                Port    5
16          River-site    2
17          Roman fort    1
18          Roman Fort    1
19    Roman settlement    3
20               Rural   22
21          Settlement    2
22               urban    1
23               Urban  123
24               Villa    4
25                 Wic   13`

Then to plot

> ggplot(v, aes(x=Settlement, y=freq)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='lightblue', color='black')

This however shows settlement type on the x axis instead of stacking the settlement types. This is missing date data. I would like to bin them into 100 year bins from 1-1500 and make a stacked bar graph of settlement types per bin to illustrate presence over time.

Comment: We need some more information here. What is the variable that you would like to use to bin? Start? End? Mid?

Comment: Mid would be most appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. The `cut` function is very useful in situations like this where you need to create a categorical variable based on some range of a continuous variable. I've gone the `Tidyverse` route but there are base R options as well.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Some dummy data that resembles your problem
s <- data.frame(ID = 1:100,
                Settlement = c(rep('Urban', 50), rep('Rural', 20), rep('Military', 10), rep('Castle', 20)),
                Start = signif(rnorm(100, 500, 100), 2),
                End = signif(rnorm(100, 1000, 100), 2))
s$Mid <- s$Start + ((s$End - s$Start) / 2)

# Find the range of the mid variable to decide on cut locations
r <- range(s$Mid)

# Make a new factor variable based year bins - you will need to change to match your actual data
s$group <- cut(s$Mid, 5, labels = c('575-640', '641-705', '706-770', '771-835', '836-900'))

# Frequency count per factor level
grouped <- s %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  count(Settlement)

# You'll need to clean up axis labels, etc.
ggplot(grouped, aes(x = group, y = n, fill = Settlement)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]